# Print out dictionary from file

Tags: python, file, dictionary

```
E;Z;X;Y
```

I tried

```
    dl= defaultdict(list)
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip().split(';')
        for x in line:
            dl[line[0]].append(line[1:4])
    dl=dict(dl)

    print (votep)
```

It print out too many results. I have an init that reads the file.

What ways can I edit to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `csv` module could be really handy here, just use a semicolon as your delimiter and a simple dict comprehension will suffice:

```
with open('filename.txt') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
    votep = {k: vals for k, *vals in reader}
    print(votep)
```

Without using `csv` you can just use `str.split`:

```
with open('filename.txt') as file:
    votep = {k: vals for k, *vals in (s.split(';') for s in file)}
    print(votep)
```

Further simplified without the comprehension this would look as follows:

```
votep = {}
for line in file:
    key, *vals = line.split(';')
    votep[key] = vals
```

And FYI, `key, *vals = line.strip(';')` is just multiple variable assignment coupled with iterable unpacking. The star just means put whatever’s left in the iterable into vals after assigning the first value to key.

Comment: Interesting I did not know about this. Do you know of a way to do it without the csv being implemented?

Comment: Yes, I’ll add an option without using `csv` although I don’t see a reason not to use it as it’s built into python.

Comment: I think it will help in my understanding. I appreciate it.

Comment: I just added an option without `csv`

Answer (score 0):

if you read file in list object, there is a simple function to iterate over and convert it to dictionary you expect:

```
a = [
    'A;X;Y;Z',
    'B;Y;Z;X',
    'C;Y;Z;X',
    'D;Z;X;Y',
    'E;Z;X;Y',
    ]

def vp(a):
    dl = {}
    for i in a:
        split_keys = i.split(';')
        dl[split_keys[0]] = split_keys[1:]
    print(dl)
```

Comment: Using a `defaultdict` is unnecessary using this approach.